# HOw to connect to Historian Database through java?

Tags: database, spring-jdbc, historian

I want to connect to Historian Database through Java. In .net we can connect it through `OleDb provider`. I have connectionString as:

```
"Provider=ihOLEDB.iHistorian;Data Source= IpAddress; user id= abc;password= xyz"
```

I tried to connect using above string and `JdbcDriverManager`,but it is giving me below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for Provider=IhOLEDB.iHistorian.1:Data Source= IP Address; user id= abc; password= xyz
```

Which `Jdbc driverManager` can be used to connect historian database? Is there any other way to connect to Historian instead of `Jdbc Drivermanager`?

Answer (score 1):

as a former employee of GE IP. 
i have to say, iH does not provide JDBC driver.
so the best way is to buy a third party  ADO-JDBC bridge.
jadoZoom (ADO Bridge for ODBC and OLE DB). GE IP  uses it in its product realtime portal to access iH.

the other way is try to use JACOB, Java COM bridge. due to iH provides com component interface (ihsdk.dll))to access data.However it is not a easy way.